# Url path in Symfony

Tags: symfony, filepath

Need to save data in text file. not able to get the correct text file path. Please suggest.

now, I am trying by using this code `$file_url= "{{ asset('/temp_files/calender.txt') }}";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($file_url, 'w') or die("can't open file1");`

but not getting the exact path.

Comment: where exactly are you trying to execute that code? in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Use templating.helper.assets, like so

```
$this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl('bundles/somename/other/calendar.txt')
```

Where bundles/somename exists in your web/bundles folder.  If you don't have anything in your web/bundles folder, then run the following command:

```
php app/console assets:install ./web --symlink
```

The *other* folder listed above will be one your create in the Resources/public folder of your bundle.